# Contar cuantos arrays existen dentro de un array anidado usando recursión

Tags: javascript, recursión

## Problema a solucionar:

En este problema me piden contar cuantos arrays hay en un array anidado. Lo que yo plantee fue recorrer el arreglo con un for, y si encontraba un índice de ese arreglo que contenga otro arreglo, le sumaba al contador, ahora mi problema es cuando tengo que aplicar la recursión y recorrer el arreglo interno, al plantearlo así como esta acá me arroja 5

```
function countDeep(arr) {
  let count = 1;
 
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i]) === true){
      count++
      if (arr[i].length > 1) {
        return count + countDeep(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countDeep([ 1, 2, 3, [ 4, [ 5, 6 ] ], 7, [ 8 ], 9]));
```

Comment: Es necesario usar recursión?

Comment: ¿No deberías empezar el contador en 0?

Comment: @lsanchezo si, es necesario la recursion

Comment: @Jacobo lo intente, pero me arroja otro valor mas grande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
var count = 0;

function countDeep(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr) === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      countDeep(arr[i]);
    }
    count++
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countDeep([2, [1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [1, 2], 6]], 7, [8], 9]]));
```

De esta forma la función primero comprueba si es un array, y si lo es lo recorre y vuelve a ejecutar la misma función recursivamente en sus subarrays, y cada vez que sale del bucle en cualquiera de ellos incrementa en uno el contador, hasta que regresa a la primera ejecución devolviendo el total de ellos.

### Otra forma sin variables globales

Si tal como expresas en los comentarios, lo quieres sin el contador como variable global, esta solución pasándolo como parámetro también funciona bien:

```js
function countDeep(arr, count = 0) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr) === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      count = countDeep(arr[i], count);
    }
    count++
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countDeep([2, [1, [2], 3, [4, [5, [1, [2]], 6]], 7, [8], 9]]));
```

En este caso lo que hacemos es inicializar el contador en 0 en la primera llamada a la función, la cual hacemos sin pasarle el parámetro, para después irlo incrementando del mismo modo que en el caso anterior, con la excepción de que hacemos dos cosas nuevas en esta línea:

```
          count = countDeep(arr[i], count);
```

1. Le pasamos el valor de **count** como parámetro dentro de la recursión, pues al no se global necesita saber que valor tiene durante la recursión: `countDeep(arr[i], count)`
2. Recogemos el valor de la recursión de la función en la variable **count** de nuevo con la asignación

```
          count = countDeep(arr[i], count);
```

### Otra posible solución con variable local

Aportada por @Mateo en los comentarios

```js
function countDeep(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(arr) === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      count += countDeep(arr[i]);
    }
    count++
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countDeep([1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 1, [2], 6]], 7, [8], 9]));
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porque declaras count fuera de la función?

Comment: Por que es recursiva, y si lo declaro dentro se reinicializará de nuevo perdiendo el sumatorio que lleve anteriormente. Pruébalo con tu array y verás que funciona (el que he puesto yo es ligeramente diferente).

Comment: Si, si me funciona pero quería entender el porque a fuera, muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso siempre es  así en la recursión ? si tengo un contador al llamarlo en la nueva recursión de reinicia? como puedo evitarlo?

Comment: puedes pasarlo como parámetro a la funcion recursiva supongo, algo asi como `countDeep(arr, count)` y luego manejarlo desde dentro correctamente

Comment: @LuisFernandoAlvarez Acabo de incluir en mi respuesta tu proposición de no usar una variable global como contador, sino como parámetro, para que lo veas

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias! también encontré otra forma de hacerlo usando Closure, ya la agrego por acá, para que la veas, sin usar variable global

Comment: O en lugar de pasar `count` como parámetro puedes tener `count` como variable local y en lugar de `count = countDeep(..., count)` puedes usar `count += countDeep(...)`. Por cierto, **profundidad** es **depth**.

Comment: @Mateo perfecto, gracias por el aporte. Con tu permiso me he tomado la libertad de incluirlo en la respuesta.

Comment: @LuisFernandoAlvarez Casi mejor que agrege tu solución a mi respuesta en lugar de dejarlo en la pregunta, o bien agregas tu una respuesta con tu solución.  En las preguntas no debemos poner las soluciones o respuestas.

Comment: Listo, ya agregue la solución en una respuesta a parte, es mi primera publicación

Comment: lo que no se hacer es que corra el codigo, asi como el tuyo

Comment: @masterguru ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

## Solución usando closure:

Otra manera de hacerlo es usando una función interna (hija) , que al invocar al padre retorne la función hija, y esa función hija retorna el contador. en esta ocasión el contador no se ve afectado por la recursión, ya que no vive en el contexto de la función hija.

Nota: cualquier otro detalle que haya pasado en la descripción de esta forma de la solución ó si hice un mal uso de los conceptos, me lo hacen saber por los comentarios. Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación y aun desconozco mucho.

```
function countDeep(arr) {

  var count = 0;

  function contar(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a) === true) {
      count++
      for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        contar(a[i]);
      }
    }
    return count;
  } return contar(arr);
}
console.log(countDeep([1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8], 9]));
```